# BASH->Python (2.6) piping

Tags: command-line, bash, python

I need to translate this line of Bash into Python:

```
sample1=($(/bin/cat /proc/meminfo | egrep 'MemTotal|MemFree|Cached|SwapTotal|SwapFree|AnonPages|Dirty|Writeback|PageTables|HugePages_' | awk ' { print $2} ' | pr -t -T --columns=15 --width=240))
```

I know I need to use Popen and communicate I just don't know how to rearrange it.

Any help?

Comment: You may get the support you need here, but your probably best off asking this question in SO or Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need popen - popen is what you use to start a process. We don't need to start another process.

And you don't need to be piping things to/from STDIN/STDOUT ;

`/proc/meminfo` follows the same rules as everything else in *nix.

- Everything is a file

You can just open `/proc/meminfo` and process it like you would any other file.

```
f = open('/proc/meminfo')
for l in f:
    # do stuff with the line from the file
```

- Create a dictionary of the line items you want
- Find those items (write a function `is_interesting(line)` or something)
- Do the string processing you need